# I have a sauna that requires 25A & 120V and has a plug that fits my 20A recepticles

Tags: electrical

My new house has typical 15A receptacles and 14 gauge wire. In a few places it has 20A receptacles and 12 gauge wire.

My girlfriend moved into a new house with me and brought an infrared sauna. The sauna has a plug which fits in the 20A receptacles **BUT** the sauna indicates it needs 25A/120V. So would I need to use a 30A breaker and run 10 gauge wire to a receptacle similar to the same receptacle as the 20A circuits? Are there receptacles which look like my 20A receptacles but are rated for 25A (or higher)? What do I search for? It looks like a NEMA 5-20P but the installation manual says it requires 25A.

Thanks.

Comment: Make/model #? With two exceptions (15A plugs can fit 20A receptacles, and there are no 40A receptacles so 50A receptacles are used for 40A devices), the plug, receptacle and breaker size must match and the wire must be large enough. So no, with rare exceptions (welders are strange, for example) if a device actually needs 25A then it needs a 25A or 30A breaker and 10 AWG (or larger) wire. Actually it gets even more complicated - many things (but I don't know about a sauna) have to be rated for 125% - e.g., if you have 24A EVSE (car charging) then it goes on a 30A breaker - so 25A is an odd size

Comment: unless it is 25A *not* continuous, in which case it gets a 25A breaker. But putting a 20A plug on a 25A device sounds rather problematic. **Make/model #** would definitely help. And check if it has a UL or ETL listing.

Comment: You should feed that beast with 30 Amp circuit

Comment: Even a 30A could be problematic, 210.21(B)(2) says max amp on 30A receptacle is 24A. (I don't know why it isn't called a 24A  receptacle!)

Comment: What do the installation instructions call for? Any UL/ETL certified device will have installation instructions that will call out _all_ these details. In order for the UL listing have validity, it _must_ be installed in accordance with those instructions. If it doesn't have a UL/ETL listing, send it back to Amazon/alibaba/wherever and get a refund, then get one that does.

Answer (score 6):

### If the item is UL Listed (or ETL or CSA), then use it according to instructions.

Because UL has taken into account how the appliance will use power, and has determined it's appropriate for the type of socket is factory-provided.

However, if the documentation is indeed telling you to use a 25A breaker with it, then this will require a dedicated circuit to that appliance.  This is on its face a violation of NEC 210.21, however it may be permitted under one of the exceptions.  Such an exception must be a circuit dedicated to that one appliance, as the breaker protection would be insufficient for 120V loads at large.

### Usually, high power 120V appliances are scams

If it is not UL Listed, then it was not legal to sell and is not safe to use. **Send it back to Amazon**, it wasn't even sold by Amazon, it was sold by a foreign 3rd party.  A lot of cheap Cheese junk is being shoveled onto our shores designed for "110V" but taking more than 16 amps.  That is not how North American power is done.  When power gets that big, we switch to 240V.

The standard scam these days is to take a high power appliance and say it is "110V" and show a standard plug on it. This makes people more confident about buying it, They make you think it's a miracle appliance that can just plug onto 110V when the ones at Home Depot cannot.  **But this is a lie**. It can't plug into a normal socket because it takes way too much power!  That's **why** the Home Depot ones are 240V.

The 25A size is far beyond what is possible for standard sockets.  There is an obscure socket type used for travel trailers, but it is a tiny bit too big for that size (a mistake no ***competent*** manufacturer would make, and they wouldn't design it to just miss.

As such, it appears your only option is the NEMA 14-50 RV plug, also used on ranges.  You will not use one of the two hot wires.

Comment: The sauna was bought years ago before I met my partner. She brought it with her when we moved in together. It wasn't bought on Amazon. It is a California based company. It was purchased at Costco.

Reading the instructions that I found online, the sauna is a 20A/120V device. But looking at the electronics on the actual sauna it is marked:

`
* Breaker: 25A
* Input Voltage: 120V/60HZ
* Power Range: 900-2300W
* Current Range: 7-20A
`

I'll just consult a local electrician.